# Model item passed does not match IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Model:

```
public class Tables: DbContext
{
    public IEnumerable<Thing> Thing { get; set; }
    public List<Thing2> Thing2 { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Example.MainTable> MainTables { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Example.Table2> Tables2 { get; set; }

}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Example.MainTable>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ABC()
    {
        var model = new Example.Models.Tables();

        string ABC = "ABC";

        model.MainTables = db.Example.Where(d => d.ColumnName.Contains(ABC)).ToList();

        model.Tables2 = (from d in db.MainTables.ToList()
                              join j in db.Tables2.ToList() on d.AssignID equals j.ID
                              select new Tables2() { Name = j.Name });

        List<Tables> allTables = new List<Tables>();
        allTables.Add(model);
        return View(allTables);
    }
```

Error Message:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Example.Models.Tables], but this dictionary requires a model item of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Example.MainTable].

Attempt 2 (deleted the last 2 lines before return in the controller and replaced):

```
 return View(model);
```

Error Message:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Example.Models.Tables', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Example.MainTable]'.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change the model on your view to `@model IEnumerable<Example.Tables>`
or make following changes in your controller

```
List<MainTable> allTables = new List<MainTable>();
allTables.Add(model.MainTables);
```